# Browser Keyboard shortcuts not working

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, autohotkey

I recently switched to a PC ( from a laptop). I use keyboard shortcuts extensively for Chrome (and other browsers), but they're not working on the PC.

Specifically, `Ctrl`+`T` for new tab and `Ctrl`+`Tab`
for switching between Tabs are not working. However `Ctrl`+`W` for closing Tab works fine.(I don't use others that ms I have no idea why it is that way.

Also this is not a Browser specific problem, as it is consistent across all the browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Tor). Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Is there any way I could fix this by a Auto-hotkey script? I use Windows 8.1

Comment: Do key combinations like Ctrl+Z, V, C, P work as expected in say notepad?

Comment: @spikey_richie  Yes all of them work , `Ctrl`+`P` (Print) also works in the browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably it's not your keyboard but just a few ideas...

- If you have Autohotkey installed, have you checked the key log?

  - (that will tell you if those key presses are being detected)
- Do you have any other uncommon/computer-specific applications running that may be grabbing certain shortcut key combinations?

  - Try exiting everything possible
  - i.e., Shutting down keyboard/mouse/driver programs running in the tray, etc.
- If you remote into that pc from another computer, does it have the same problem symptoms?
- Have you tried using the shortcut with the right control key vs. the left control key on your keyboard?

Autohotkey can be used to work around plenty of things like this, but if there's a program grabbing a hotkey (shortcut combination) globally then it may or may not help as a direct fix unless you find the source of the problem. Presumably you could still re-map the shortcut keys to something else using Autohotkey, but that wouldn't really be ideal unless your keyboard hardware was physically broken (which does not appear to be the case).

Comment: Actually I found out that its an issue with my keyboard, I went to a website to check keyboard input and found out that my keyboard apparantely doesn't register when some keys are pressed together. Autohotkey works fine and all browser and other shortcuts work  as expected. Sorry for late reply,  I totally forgot about this post